# A pin of socket LGA775 for processor is broken

Tags: motherboard, lga775, processor-socket

One of my client's motherboards has a problem with the processor socket (LGA775): a pin is broken.

Are there any solutions to this or do I have to change the motherboard?

Answer (score 2):

In principle you can resolder/repair the broken pin. If this is feasible in practice depends on many things, such as

- Is the broken pin accessible for soldering?
- Do you have the equipment for soldering`?
- Is there other stuff nearby on the board that you might damage?

And finally:

- Do you have experience soldering?

You can post a picture of the broken pin so others can have a look and give advice.

In my opinion: Unless it's a very expensive motherboard, or you can answer yes to all the questions above, a repair will probably not be practical.

You can still sell the board on Ebay or similar, noting it is defective. Someone may buy it to repair it.